# Hide Main PST file in email account list

Tags: file-management, microsoft-office-2013

I recently resetted my Outlook by deleting all PST, OST and temporary files. When I restarted Outlook, it asked me where to store a PST file (Main file, I think), so I put it somewhere. Then I set up the first email account. The problem is, when I go to the emails tab, there are to entries named "Cubinator". The first is the main file that I only wanted to be used for calendar and the second is my email account. **Is there a way to hide the main file entry from the email account list? If not, is it somehow possible to merge the main file (used as calendar) with the email account file (used for emailing obviously)?**

Somewhere on StackOverflow I read that I have to create the main file first, then the email account, then I have to close Outlook and overwrite the main file with the email account file. But this doesn't work, because the main file is a PST file and the email account file (at least for IMAP) is OST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I created the main file first, then I create my email account. In the account manager under the Data Files tab I set my email account file to the default/standard file, waited for transferring configuration data and deleted the old file. Then I imported my calendar (I exported it before) into my email account and it worked :)